# How to configure newrelic notification on error traced from web-application

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am using `error_collector` to collect a specific error from web application

```
NewRelic::Agent.agent.error_collector.notice_error("error message")
```

I can see my traced error on "Newrelic error dashboard", as mentioned [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/applications-dashboards/errors-dashboard)

**I want to trigger an email to developer-group when this error traced on Newrelic, Is there any way to configure this?**

I am having "key-transaction" for this request, but "key transaction" is sending notification email based on "Apdex scores" and "error rates".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently New Relic alerts for an applications error rate, and Apdex score, or a servers CPU, IO, memory usage, and full disk.

Downtime alerts are available for both applications and servers. New Relic does not provide alerts when a specific error is traced.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, have raised same question to newrelic support, and they replied the same .. :)

Comment: This thread old, however, what you can do as of today is to create a metric for this error and then create an Alert for this metric.